# What is the best way to migrate from google appengine datastore to google cloud bigtable?

Tags: database, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

I have an appengine datastore and I want to migrate to google cloud bigtable.
What is the best way to do that ?

Thanks for your answers, 
Yanice

Answer (score 1):

## These storage systems are quite different.

**Schema:**

- Cloud Datastore is a schema-less document database, while
- Cloud Bigtable is a wide-column database with a schema (simple schema, but a still schema)

**Availability & Replication:**

- Cloud Datastore is Multi-Regional (99.95% Availability SLA) handling replication for you
- Cloud Bigtable is Zonal (99.9% Availability SLA) where you need to handle replication yourself

**Workloads:**

- Cloud Datastore is designed for operational workloads, handling live user path requests
- Cloud Bigtable is designed for analytical workloads, handling non-critical path requests such as reporting or background queries.

**So, you'll need to:**

- Analysis your data in Cloud Datastore to determine schemas you will need in Cloud Bigtable
- For non-trivial data models determine how you will modify your app to handle it (such as composite indexes)
- Determine if the availability & replication setup meets or need, building infrastructure on top to handle it if needed (not recommended)
- Write a job to move the data, potentially using something like Cloud Dataflow

Generally speaking, you won't want to move from Datastore to Bigtable unless you meet very specific requirements:

- Only using Datastore as a Key-Value store
- Can tolerate a Zonal database
- Are running analytical workloads

Answer (score 0):

Start by looking at the [Java Managed VM sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/java/managed-vms).  The JSON code will probably be most interesting. (Cloud Bigtable doesn't yet work with regular GAE with Java or Python - due to a gRPC limitation).

Bigtable has one key per row, if your database design can work with that, its a fairly easy conversion.  For other sorts, you will probably want to create MapReduce jobs.

Comment: "Cloud Bigtable doesn't yet work with regular GAE with Java or Python - due to a gRPC limitation" Whoa, good to know.  What about Go appengine?  Is this limitation documented anywhere?  I totally missed it if so.  I note that these library docs (https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/go/reference) say "If your program is run on Google App Engine or Google Compute Engine, using the Application Default Credentials is the simplest option." which certainly implies GAE is supported.

Comment: It requires a custom runtime that means that you can't debug locally, but you can run using GAE -- I'll be updating instructions and samples today or tomorrow.

Comment: Code samples would be _awesome_.  I assume those will show up [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-golang/tree/master/examples/bigtable)?  I see there is already a ManagedVM example but not a vanilla GAE one.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101156/connect-to-bigtable-within-gae  Hope to have it done tonight.