# Connect to Cloud Bigtable from Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-bigtable

It appears that I cannot create a connection from Java class running on AppEngine.

I use the following library/dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigtable</groupId>
   <artifactId>bigtable-hbase-1.1</artifactId>
   <version>0.1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

And the following lines of code:

```java
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.*;
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
connection  = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
```

It appears that the `ConnectionFactory.createConnection()` method tries to use a restricted class.

Could you help us in explaining how we can use this on GAE?

I get the following error when running locally on devserver:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.management.ManagementFactory is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at     com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:52)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.<clinit>(ReflectionUtils.java:137)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.UserProvider.instantiate(UserProvider.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
    at org.energyworx.datastore.BigTableTSStorage.<init>(BigTableTSStorage.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:373)
    ... 71 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the sample on [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/java/gae-flexible-helloworld).

Comment: Hmm, just re-read your post and saw that you mentioned "can only run in cloud", how can I run it locally for development? This is not supported yet? since the Jetty one does not support the GAE API's we cannot use that one for testing.

Comment: The latest gcloud only works with the google environment, which unfortunately doesn't yet support the gRPC based APIs which Bigtable uses for performance -- this is why we need a custom runtime, which we base off the standard one, but add in alpn-boot.

It is possible to roll back your gcloud to the prior version that supported local debugging of a custom VM w/ GAE APIs.

Comment: Should be fixed now -- Thanks.